# How to change textbox Caret?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change my textbox's Caret from ( | ) symbol to ( _ ) using css.
Cursor which we have in command line (cmd). is there any possible way?

Comment: This is actually possible, but complicated. Let me see if I can make a fiddle

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It is a duplicate. But you have pointed to a wrong question :-/

Comment: @TheDarkKnight, err... do you mean the questioner was referring to the control's caret instead of the mouse cursor? That's a possibility indeed, reopening...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes that's what i am trying to say Control's Caret

Comment: @Wouter Huysentruit ty